# Common Table Expression syntax

Tags: postgresql, cte, syntax, style

Considering a query with CTEs:

```sql
WITH cte_0 AS (
          SELECT SUM(col_0)
          FROM table_0
          WHERE condition_00
          AND condition_01
    ), 
    cte_1 AS (
          SELECT SUM(col_1)
          FROM table_0
          WHERE condition_10
          AND condition_11
    )
    SELECT (
          ((SELECT * FROM cte_0) * 100) / (SELECT * FROM cte_1),
          ((SELECT * FROM cte_0) + 100) * (SELECT * FORM cte_1)
    ) FROM cte_0, cte_1
```

Would it be correct to leave the last `FROM` out? And do I get a tuple of two numbers with a query like that? Or do I need a new table from which I `SELECT *` to get two numbers?

I just started my first PostgreSQL project and I've seen different styles of writing it. All comments on the style are warmly welcomed. I have not found any suitable online PostgreSQL platform for testing queries. Are there any?

Question edited to include conditions and a more complicated result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes, it makes no sense to have that extra `FROM`,** because you are not selecting anything from those tables, the results come entirely from the subqueries.

Either that, or you should remove the `FROM` in the subqueries, which would be more idiomatic.

In other words, you could also do this (note the use of an explicit `CROSS JOIN` rather than implicit comma-joins)

```
WITH cte_0 AS (
          SELECT SUM(col_0) sum0
          FROM table_0
          WHERE condition_00
          AND condition_01
    ), 
    cte_1 AS (
          SELECT SUM(col_1) sum1
          FROM table_0
          WHERE condition_10
          AND condition_11
    )
    SELECT
          sum0 * 100 / sum1,
          (sum0 + 100) * sum1
    FROM cte_0
    CROSS JOIN cte_1
```

Having said that, **you shouldn't do any of these three options.** You can do both aggregations from a single table reference.

In your (now modified) question, you can use conditional aggregation. In PostgreSQL this is done using the `FILTER` clause.

```
SELECT
  SUM(t0.col_0) FILTER (WHERE condition_00 AND condition_01) * 100
    / SUM(t0.col_1) FILTER (WHERE condition_10 AND condition_11),
  (SUM(t0.col_0) FILTER (WHERE condition_00 AND condition_01) + 100)
    * SUM(t0.col_1) FILTER (WHERE condition_10 AND condition_11)
FROM table0 t0;
```

Comment: I totally agree with the use of `FILTER` to get a single scan over `table0`, but I would still use a CTE or subquery to avoid the repetition

Comment: @Bergi could you add your solution as an answer so that I and all the future beginners finding the question could learn from it?